# What is wrong on this sidebar component? It shows raw text "}" must be wrapped in explicit text component

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, native-base

[image: error image]

This code worked last day. When we try to separate it shows this error. I am sure that trouble is in this component as far as other components work perfectly. What can be the reason for it?  You can check code on the below:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import {
  Content,
  List,
  Icon,
  ListItem,
  Left,
  Input,
  Item,
  Thumbnail
} from "native-base";
import Exponent from "expo"
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const datas = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    route: "Home",
    icon: "home",
  },

  {
    name: "Business",
    route: "Home",
    icon: "briefcase",
  },
  {
    name: "Education",
    route: "Home",
    icon: "book",
  },
  {
    name: "Life Style",
    route: "Home",
    icon: "shirt",
  },
  {
    name: "Tech",
    route: "Home",
    icon: "phone-portrait",
  },
  {
    name: "Profile",
    route: "Profile",
    icon: "contact",
  },
  {
    name: "Settings",
    route: "Settings",
    icon: "settings",
  },
  {
    name: "Contact",
    route: "Contact",
    icon: "mail",
  },
  {
    name: "Log Out",
    route: "Signin",
    icon: "log-out",
  },
];

const DrawerContent = props => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Content style={{marginTop: 20}}>
      <View style={styles.avatarview}>
      <Thumbnail source={require("../img/profile4.jpg")} style={{marginTop:40}}/>
      <Text style={styles.profiletext}> Jhon </Text>
      </View>
        <List
          dataArray={datas}
          renderRow={data =>
            <ListItem
              button
              noBorder
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
            >
              <Left style={{marginLeft: 15}}>
                <Icon
                  active
                  name={data.icon}
                  style={styles.navicon}

                />
                <Text style={styles.navtext}>
                  {data.name}
                </Text>
                  }
              </Left>
            </ListItem>}
        />
      </Content>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    height: screenHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Exponent.Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  avatarview: {
    height:200,
    backgroundColor:"#ffffff",
    alignItems:"center"
  },
  profiletext:{
    marginTop:30,
    color:"#ffffff"
  },

navicon:{
   color: "#222222",
   fontSize: 22,
   marginTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 1.8 : 4,
},
navtext:{
  color: "#222222",
   fontSize: 22,
    marginLeft: 15
},


};

export default DrawerContent;
```

We are using native-base and expo. Most interesting is that eslint doesn't show any line which can cause it. What is wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: You have an extra `}` right after `</Text>` in `DrawerContent`

Comment: This error arrived due to some extra space after, between <View> and </View>. You need to check this where actually added space by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                </Text>
              }
          </Left>
```

You need to remove this bracket.

Comment: thanks a lot it works.